# SAS: use dynamic macro variable in loop in macro program

Tags: loops, sas, sas-macro

I want to achieve the same as:

```
data train_Sex(keep=Name Sex) train_Age(keep=Name Age) train_Height(keep=Name Height) train_Weight(keep=Name Height);
    set sashelp.class;
run;
```

using a macro program with a list of variables. 
As far as I went:

```
* Build macro program;
%macro build_sets(var_list);
    %let nwords = %sysfunc(countw(&var_list));

    %do i=1 %to &nwords;
        call symput("variable",  %scan(&var_list, i));

        data train_&variable(keep=Name &variable);
            set sashelp.class;
        run;

    %end;
%mend;

* Run it;
%let var_list = Sex Age Height Weight;
%build_sets(&var_list);
```

But I am lacking the knowledge how can I dynamically change the "variable" var.

Thanks!

---

similar questions:

1.[SAS dynamically declaring macro variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25577984/sas-dynamically-declaring-macro-variable)
2. [Using a dynamic macro variable in a call symput statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20454690/using-a-dynamic-macro-variable-in-a-call-symput-statement)
3. [Dynamic macro variable access SAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50914620/dynamic-macro-variable-access-sas)

Comment: Your macro isn't quite attempting to recreate the data set, instead it's pulling each variable out into an individual data set. If you're trying to create a fact/dim table there's a macro on SAS communities that does this automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were close. below thing should work for you. call symput is part of datastep  is used to create macrovariable from dvariables and hence the issue.

```
 %macro build_sets(var_list);
;

%do i=1 %to  %sysfunc(countw(&var_list));
    %let variable=  %scan(&var_list, &i));

    data train_&variable(keep=Name &variable);
        set sashelp.class;
    run;

%end;
%mend;

 * Run it;
%let var_list = Sex Age Height Weight;
%build_sets(&var_list);
```